# SP 2013 view: Count in group complete / total

Tags: list-view, calculated-column, grouping

I have a standard list view with grouping by period, which shows me only total count in group. I'd like to add one more parameter to display, based on calculated column with yes\no output and Completed\In Progress display values. 
 [image: Now i have]

[image: I would like to have]

Answer (score 1):

It won't be possible OOTB way. You can add another grouping based on Yes/No or Status but not both.

Comment: I'm not taking about OOTB. I'm asking if there is any way of script solution, or some alternatives. i found a sort of solution for 2010 [here](https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/summing-calculated-columns-in-group-by-in-sharepoint-list-dataview-webpart/). But its not quite fit to me.